# Rust Sqlx Custom implementation FromRow mapping

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

Need:
I am trying to implement sql:: frowrow, but an error is reported when defining it

in fn new(pool: Arc)
_from_row parameter error

```
pub struct Table<'c, T>
where
    T: FromRow<'c, MySqlRow>,
{
    pub pool: Arc<MySqlPool>,
    _from_row: fn(&MySqlRow) -> Result<T, sqlx::Error>,
    phantom: PhantomData<&'c T>,

}

impl<'c, T> Table<'c, T>
where
    T: FromRow<'c, MySqlRow>,
{
    fn new(pool: Arc<MySqlPool>) -> Self {
        Table {
            pool,
            phantom: PhantomData,
            _from_row: T::from_row, 
            //implementation of `sqlx::FromRow` is not general enough
            //doesn't satisfy where-clause
            //note: ...`T` must implement `sqlx::FromRow<'0, sqlx::mysql::MySqlRow>`, for some specific lifetime `'0`...
            //note: ...but it actually implements `sqlx::FromRow<'c, sqlx::mysql::MySqlRow>`
            
        }
    }
}
```

```
pub struct Database<'c> {
    pub groups: Arc<Table<'c, Group>>,
}
```

impl from_row method in   Group model

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use sqlx::mysql::MySqlRow;
use sqlx::{FromRow, Row};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct Group {
    pub id: u64,
    pub name: String,
}

impl<'c> FromRow<'c, MySqlRow> for Group {
    fn from_row(row: &'c MySqlRow) -> Result<Self, sqlx::Error> {
        Ok(Group {
            id: row.get(0),
            name: row.get(1),
        })
    }
}
```

Error:

```
implementation of `sqlx::FromRow` is not general enough

doesn't satisfy where-clause

note: ...`T` must implement `sqlx::FromRow<'0, sqlx::mysql::MySqlRow>`, for some specific lifetime `'0`...
note: ...but it actually implements `sqlx::FromRow<'c, sqlx::mysql::MySqlRow>`
```

Question:
I have implements the method sqlx::FromRow<'c, sqlx::mysql::MySqlRow> in the 'Group' model

Sqlx dependency:

```
sqlx = { version = "0.5.11", features = ["chrono","runtime-actix-rustls","mysql"] }
```

Comment: The code compiles by if the type of `_from_row` in `struct Table` if changed to `_from_row: fn(&'c MySqlRow) -> Result<T, sqlx::Error>` (notice the `'c`).

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really this problem that caused the mistake